# Stored Procedure - Standards and Best practices checking

Tags: sql

I am Looking for an utility which can review stored procedures for Standards, best practices etc. Env is SQL Server 2005.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that comes to mind is this utility:

- [SQL Server
  2005 Best Practices Analyzer (August
  2008)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=DA0531E4-E94C-4991-82FA-F0E3FBD05E63)
- [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Best
  Practices Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0fd439d7-4bff-4df7-a52f-9a1be8725591)

Read this [article by Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/05/sql-server-2005-best-practices-analyzer-tutorial-sample-example/).